# Address on cover letter for PhD application

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, application-cover-letter

There are 3 PhD positions advertised on university's website and I am interested in two of them. University welcomes to give more than one choices for which candidate should be considered. For both positions requirements are similar. I know the names of professors who will supervise these PhDs but I am not sure if they are the only ones who will judge the applications. Moreover, it is written to upload cover letter in university's application system not to sent to Professors directly.

I am confused how should I address Cover Letter to be considered for both positions. Currently, I have the following

> PhD Candidate Search Committee
>
> {Department name}
>
> {University name}
>
> {City, Country}
>
> {postcode}
>
> Dear Members of the Search Committee,

Is it a good way to address in cover letter?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, what you have written already is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is fine.  If you’re game you *might* want to separately send a copy of the letter to the persons of interest, indicating in a polite and serious email that you have applied and why you are very interested in this position.

Answer (score 1):

The form of the letter you are proposing is appropriate. You are applying to the institution, not to the professors.

I agree with [astronat](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/49043/astronat) ([above](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/110402/100521)) but with the recommendation that your cover letter and CV be in attachments. The actual message should be far more succinct, with the right keywords to catch the eye of the professors. Most of us have overflowing mailboxes and the attention spans of goldfish, and won't read past the first paragraph. [Bottom Line Up Front!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLUF_(communication))